# Payment Transaction Failed Reminder

Tags: magento-1.9, payment

I just received this email below. There usually is something under the ‘`Reason`’ heading, however there is nothing here.

> Payment transaction failed.
>
> Reason
>
> Checkout Type onepage
>
> Customer: Sakthi Anand Velusamy

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the log files? Is there anything in system.log or exception.log related to the failed payment transaction?